# glossaries alters main text

Tags: glossaries

Some languages use inflexions and conjugations.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{tēju} % how the word is found in text
{
  name=tēja, %nominative for the glossary entry
  description={a drink}
}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
Dzert \gls{tēju}.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

after compiling (with `xelatex` - see [glossary with diacritic marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461428/glossary-with-diacritic-marks?answertab=active#tab-top)) unfortunately the main text got altered from

"Dzert tēju"

to

"Dzert tēja"

How to fix?

Comment: Your example is not compilable. I doubt that the glossar entry `tēju` is possible at all -- the glossar entry must use letters only, as far as I know

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461428/glossary-with-diacritic-marks?answertab=active#tab-top. `xelatex` is required.

Comment: Yes, I know. But you can drop `inputenc` then... Again, I would not use non-ASCII letters as glossary label names

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, how will the glossary find the entry in the text then?

Comment: By the way: `name=tēja` will print `tēja` of course, when `\gls{tēju}` is applied. If you want another case like genitive etc, you have to provide special keys for this. `glossaries` can not know which case you need here.

Comment: In this example `tēju` is really just an internal label. It could just as well be replaced with `foo` and the result would be the same. If you want `glossaries` to be able to apply the correct declension to your words, extra work is needed, see for example §4.2 and §4.3 of the `glossaries` manual.

Comment: I've done something similar here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467822/how-often-do-you-refer-to-glossary-entries (for German language, however)

Comment: @moewe: Actually, the label name is something like a macro name (in a group, however) that's why non-ascii letters can be not used, unless with XeLaTeX

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I found that adding `text=tēju` to `\newglossaryentry` solves this problem.

Comment: @Viesturs: You can either add a self-answer or delete your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is obtained by using the `text` option of `\newglossaryentry`:

```
\newglossaryentry{tēju} % placeholder for the dictionary entry
{
  name=tēja, %nominative for the glossary entry
  text=tēju, %how the word should appear in the text
  description={a drink}
}
```